# How can I change the anchors of an item to attach it to the right or left of another item based on a condition?

Tags: qt, qml

The layout below works. I am showing it as reference. `startSelectionRect` is always anchored to the left of a line as I have intended.

```
Rectangle {
    id: startLine
    x: ui.selectionModel.startPixel
    width: 1
    height: parent.height
    color: QQProperties.Colors.text
}

Rectangle {
    id: startSelectionRect
    color: QQProperties.Colors.transparentSelectionBackground
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.right: startLine.left
    implicitHeight: startSelectionLayout.implicitHeight + QQProperties.Margins.small * 2
    implicitWidth: startSelectionLayout.implicitWidth + QQProperties.Margins.medium * 2

    ColumnLayout {
        id: startSelectionLayout
        spacing: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.topMargin: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.bottomMargin: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.leftMargin: QQProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.rightMargin: QQProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.fill: parent

        QQComponents.HeaderText {
            id: startText
            text: Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.startUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I try to anchor `startSelectionRect` to the right or left of a line based on a condition.

```
function selectionFromLowestBound() {
    console.log("selectionStartingOnLowestBound: ", ui.selectionModel.startPixel === ui.selectionModel.lowerBoundaryPixel);
    return ui.selectionModel.startPixel === ui.selectionModel.lowerBoundaryPixel;
}

Rectangle {
    id: startLine
    x: ui.selectionModel.startPixel
    width: 1
    height: parent.height
    color: QQProperties.Colors.text
}

Rectangle {
    id: startSelectionRect
    color: QQProperties.Colors.transparentSelectionBackground
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.right: selectionFromLowestBound() ? startLine.left : undefined
    anchors.left: !selectionFromLowestBound() ? startLine.right : undefined
    implicitHeight: startSelectionLayout.implicitHeight + QQProperties.Margins.small * 2
    implicitWidth: startSelectionLayout.implicitWidth + QQProperties.Margins.medium * 2

    ColumnLayout {
        id: startSelectionLayout
        spacing: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.topMargin: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.bottomMargin: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.leftMargin: QQProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.rightMargin: QQProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.fill: parent

        QQComponents.HeaderText {
            id: startText
            text: Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.startUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)
        }
    }
}
```

I can see with `console.log` that the condition is evaluated and that it is sometimes `true` and sometimes `false`. But `startSelectionRect` is always anchored to the right of the line. And `startSelectionRect` has lost its background color.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here I am trying to follow the answer by Amfasis, but am failing thus far.

```
function selectionFromLowestBound() {
    return ui.selectionModel.startPixel === ui.selectionModel.lowerBoundaryPixel;
}

Rectangle {
    id: startLine
    x: ui.selectionModel.startPixel
    width: 1
    height: parent.height
    color: QQProperties.Colors.text
}

Rectangle {
    id: startSelectionRect
    color: QQProperties.Colors.transparentSelectionBackground
    anchors.top: parent.top
    implicitHeight: startSelectionLayout.implicitHeight + QQProperties.Margins.small * 2
    implicitWidth: startSelectionLayout.implicitWidth + QQProperties.Margins.medium * 2

    states: [
        State {
            name: "lowerBound"
            when: selectionFromLowestBound()
            PropertyChanges {
                target: startSelectionRect
                anchors.right: startLine.left
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "upperBound"
            when: !selectionFromLowestBound()
            PropertyChanges {
                target: startSelectionRect
                anchors.left: startLine.right
            }
        } 
    ]

    ColumnLayout {
        id: startSelectionLayout
        spacing: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.topMargin: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.bottomMargin: QQProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.leftMargin: QQProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.rightMargin: QQProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.fill: parent

        QQComponents.HeaderText {
            id: startText
            text: Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.startUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add states to a QML item in which it is also possible to set different anchors. See the following example:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect

    property bool left : true

    states: [
        State {
            name: "left"
            when: rect.left
            PropertyChanges {
                target: rect
                anchors.left: parent.right
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "right"
            when: !rect.left
            PropertyChanges {
                target: rect
                anchors.right: parent.left    //note switched with above ;-)
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to set a `name` to `State`s when they are set with `when`.
Using ternary bindings like OP should work though.

Comment: @Amfasis: Thank you for your proposal! Unfortunately I haven't gotten this to work yet. See my edit if you have time. I am still trying to solve this.

Comment: @user1283776 what is the problem? BTW, you do know that the rectangle you're anchoring to is 1 pixel wide, so difficult to see maybe?

Comment: @Amfasis: I do see the line. The problem is that startSelectionRect is always anchored to one side of the line. If I change the when statements to something else that I know is always true or false, I can get the rectangle to attach to either side, so it seems like I am having a problem with the binding. I have no idea why as console.log in the selectionFromLowestBound() triggers as expected and shows different values with no effect on UI. When I get back to work I will try to add a selectionFromLowestBound() method to the model and see if that possibly helps.

Comment: @user1283776 ok. Yes I was already a bit worried about the function binding, but don't have enough knowledge on that part so didn't say. But it might be the `when` condition doesn't properly bind with function orso... but that's a question mark for me as well